# How to compose IO functions with other effects in Kotlin Arrow FX

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

We often need some request validation before handling it. With arrow v 0.8 a typical message handler looked like:

```
fun addToShoppingCart(request: AddToShoppingCartRequest): IO<Either<ShoppingCardError, ItemAddedEvent>> = fx {
    request
    .pipe (::validateShoppingCard)
    .flatMap { validatedRequest ->
        queryShoppingCart().bind().map { validatedRequest to it }         // fun queryShoppingCart(): IO<Either<DatabaseError, ShoppingCart>>
    }
    .flatMap { (validatedRequest, shoppingCart) ->
        maybeAddToShoppingCart(shoppingCart, validatedRequest)            // fun maybeAddToShoppingCart(...): Either<DomainError, ShoppingCart>
    }
    .flatMap { updatedShoppingCart ->
        storeShoppingCart(updatedShoppingCart).bind()                     // fun storeShoppingCart(ShoppingCart): IO<Either<DatabaseError, Unit>>
        .map {
            computeItemAddedEvent(updatedShoppingCart)
        }
    }
    .mapLeft(::computeShoppingCartError)
}
```

This seems to be a convenient and expressive definition of a workflow. I tried to define similar function in arrow v 0.10.5:

```
fun handleDownloadRequest(strUrl: String): IO<Either<BadUrl, MyObject>> = IO.fx {
    parseUrl(strUrl)                                                      // fun(String): Either<BadUrl,Url>
    .map {
        !effect{ downloadObject(it) }                                     // suspended fun downloadObject(Url): MyObject
    }
}
```

Which results in a compiler error "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body". The reason is both `map` and `flatMap` functions of `Either` and `Option` are not `inline`.

Indeed, the [blog post](https://www.pacoworks.com/2019/12/15/kotlin-coroutines-with-arrow-fx/) about fx says

> "Soon you will find that you cannot call suspend functions inside the
>   functions declared for Either such as the ones mentioned above, and
>   other fan favorites like map() and handleErrorWith(). For that you
>   need a concurrency library!"

So the question is why is it so and what is the idiomatic way of such composition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiomatic way is

```
fun handleDownloadRequest(strUrl: String): IO<Either<BadUrl, MyObject>> =
    parseUrl(strUrl)
      .fold({
        IO.just(it.left())  // forward the error
      }, {
        IO { downloadObject(it) }
          .attempt() // get an Either<Throwable, MyObject>
          .map { it.mapLeft { /* Throwable to BadURL */ } } // fix the left side
      })
```

Personally I wouldn't go to the deep end of IO with that one, and rewrite as a suspend function instead

```
suspend fun handleDownloadRequest(strUrl: String): Either<BadUrl, MyObject> =
    parseUrl(strUrl)
      .fold(::Left) { // forward the error
        Either.catch({ /* Throwable to BadURL */ }) { downloadObject(it) }
      }
```

What happened is, in 0.8.X the functions for `Either` used to be inlined. An *unintended* side-effect of this was that you could call suspend functions anywhere. While this is nice, it can lead to exceptions thrown (or jumping threads or deadlocks ) in the middle of a `map` or a `flatMap`, which is terrible for correctness. It's a crutch.

In 0.9 (or was it 10?) we removed that crutch and made it into something explicit in the API: `Either.catch`. We kept `fold` as inlined because it's the same as `when`, so there was no real correctness tradeoff there.

So, the recommended thing is to use `suspend` everywhere and only reach for `IO` when trying to do threading, parallelism, cancellation, retries and scheduling, or anything really advanced.

For basic use cases `suspend` and `Either.catch` is enough. To call into a `suspend` function at the edge of your program or where you need to bridge with these advanced behaviors then use `IO`.

If you want to continue using Either you can define suspend/inline versions of regular functions at your own risk; or wait until `IO<E, A>` in 0.11 where you can use [`effectEither`](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-fx/blob/deca849a1f5b551e9a4b92b67a4f577887d54fca/arrow-fx/src/main/kotlin/arrow/fx/IO.kt#L112-L119) and [`effectMapEither`](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-fx/blob/deca849a1f5b551e9a4b92b67a4f577887d54fca/arrow-fx/src/main/kotlin/arrow/fx/IO.kt#L1094-L1101).